# PDFBox to search for words. Code recognizes few words only

Tags: pdfbox, wordsearch

The code I have posted takes in 5 arguments which include the location to a pdf document and a search term. The code is to parse through the PDF document and return all the matches to the keyword in the document and return their locations depending on the format (last given argument).

The code for some reason recognizes only a few words and errors on other words. I am not sure why this is.

There seems to be no difference in these words in terms of font, size location etc.

The code can be found at  [full text search](https://github.com/leslie-lau/fulltextsearch) 
The PDF could be found at  [PDF Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ttbl_y7lT_hLf8NPh1Gz54tAWs9hXM9e/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can help you?

Comment: And please share the PDF too. A good question includes all that is needed.

Comment: Indeed, without code and an example PDF, we could try and forward your question to our crystal balls, but we cannot give you serious advice.

Comment: @Krutheeka You are talking about "the code" and "the PDF" but where are both? This question will be closed otherwise...

Comment: Hi All, I apologize, but I believe I did add my code, but someone had edited it. The code can be found at <a href="https://github.com/leslie-lau/fulltextsearch"> full text search </a>
The PDF could be found at <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ttbl_y7lT_hLf8NPh1Gz54tAWs9hXM9e/view?usp=sharing"> PDF Document </a>

Comment: It looks like "your code" actually is code of Leslie Lau. Have you considered contacting Leslie via a github issue? Leslie should be the person knowing that code best. If that does not succeed, you of course can ask here, but you should burn down the required code to a **short**, self contained example which you would add to your question.

Comment: Related - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4431